# Offseting animation start point for SVG AnimateMotion

Tags: animation, svg, offset, motion

I have a `path` in my SVG, and I want to animate 2 `rect` elements along it, using `animateMotion`. However, I want the two rectangles to start at different points along the path.

I've gotten close by using `begin` to offset the start time, but that means that one rectangle gets stuck until its time starts - which is non ideal. Is there something similar to `begin`,  like `startOffset` for text that would work?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill="none" stroke="lightgrey" id="motionPath"
    d="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" />

  <circle r="5" fill="red">
    <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"
    >
    <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  
   <circle r="5" fill="red">
    <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"
            begin="2s"
    >
      <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

For your case of a indefinitely repeated motion, the easiest solution is to set the `begin` time to a negative value. At document start time, the motion is computed to have already begun, and the animated element starts at an offset.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill="none" stroke="lightgrey" id="motionPath"
    d="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" />

  <circle r="5" fill="red">
    <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"
    >
    <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  
   <circle r="5" fill="red">
    <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"
            begin="-2s"
    >
      <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

*Note: for a non-repeated motion, you can also use the notation [`keyPoints="0.2;1"`](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#KeyPointsAttribute). This way, during the simple duration, the animated element moves from 20% to 100% along the path, but never is shown at its start.*